# No read permission on MSysObject error

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to connect to an MS Access database (.mdb) through `OleDb`. My query is

```
SELECT * FROM ListQueries
```

which fetches me the error

> SQL Execution Error.
>
> Executed SQL Statement: SELECT * FROM ListQueries
>   Error Source: Microsoft JET Database Engine
>   Error Message: Records cannot be read; No read permission on 'MSysObjects'.

Then I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15209744/17447), but it did not help. Then I saw another answer says to do this.

```
strDdl = "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl
```

I do not know how to implement that in my `web project`. Was writing something like this as per this suggestion by [@HansUp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77335/hansup)

> Alternatively, it should work from c# if you run it from an OleDb connection to the Access db

The code is,

```
OleDbConnection con;
using (con = new OleDbConnection(Connection.connectionString()))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var com = new OleDbCommand("GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin", con))
    {
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    using (var com = new OleDbCommand("Select * from ListQueries", con))
    {
        using (var dr = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                qryList.Add(SQLReaderExtensions.SafeGetString(dr, "Name"));
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

The first `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` gives me this error.

> Cannot open the Microsoft Jet engine workgroup information file.

I would really like to know *how to grant permission for an OleDb call to work*. Any suggestions will be wonderful

P.S: BTW, I am using MS Access 2010.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you do not use MS Access system objects. There are other and better ways to get the information. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Remou: Queries in MS-Access are analogous to Views in SQL for most part, IMHO.

Comment: You have a choice of ADO (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh(VS.80).aspx) and DAO. Which would you prefer? Note that in ADO there is a difference between action and select queries.

Comment: @Remou: it worked, will you post it as answer. thanks a lot for your time :) i am been sitting for hours with this. thanks a ton

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you do not use MS Access system objects. There are other and better ways to get the information.

You have a choice of [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh%28VS.80%29.aspx) and DAO. Which would you prefer? Note that in ADO there is a difference between action (adSchemaProcedures) and select queries (adSchemaViews).

For example,

```
public static List<string> GetAllQueriesFromDataBase()
{
    var queries = new List<string>();
    using (var con = new OleDbConnection(Connection.connectionString()))
    {
        con.Open();
        var dt = con.GetSchema("Views");
        queries = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME")).ToList();
    }

    return queries;
}
```

Comment: @naveen you are the c# person :)

Comment: dont embarass me more :)