# Grant read permission for MSysObjects

Tags: powershell, ms-access, metadata, adodb, office-automation

I need to get the metadata of some hundred MS Access DBs, so I need to automate the process of metadata gathering.
I want to query stuff described [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/queries/qry0002.htm), but before I can query the DBs I need read access to `MSysObjects` tables.

I Keep getting following error:

> Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MsysObjects'.

so I dug deeper:

I've read the article about similar issues in the C# section ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235430/no-read-permission-on-msysobject-error) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937703/record-cannot-be-read-no-read-permission-on-msysobjects)).

I put together a simple script which works well for creating tables and so on, but I am having problems to setup the read access.

```
$ScrUsr = $(whoami)
Write-Host $ScrUsr

$cmd = "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO [$ScrUsr]"
Write-Host $cmd

Function Invoke-ADOCommand($Db)
{
  $connection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
  $connection.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$db;" )
  $command = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Command
  $command.ActiveConnection = $connection
  $command.CommandText = $cmd
  $rs = $command.Execute()
  $connection.Close()
} 

$Db = "C:\Temp\test1.accdb"

Invoke-ADOCommand -db $Db
```

Executing the Script throws me following Error reason:

> Cannot open the Microsoft Office Access database engine workgroup information file.

How can I allow read permission on `MSysObjects`?

Comment: I don't think its the problem but your parameters for your function have an anomoly in them `Invoke-ADOCommand($Db, $Command)` you dont use `$command` when you _call_ the function so just remove it. Is that database password protected?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, already fixed, script works because the $command variable will be set in the function. Nop DB is not Password protected. I already tried also Grant to Public but this didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried this? ... `GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;`

Comment: Jepp, was my Initial Statement firing against the MdB, same errorMsg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues you must address:

1. Your code will use the Access security account *"Admin"* when interacting with the Access ACCDB database.  Other Access security accounts are only available if you have implemented Access user-level security (ULS), but that feature is only available for MDB format databases.  Therefore, with ACCDB, you can't `GRANT` anything to any account other than *"Admin"*.
2. You must include the location of the *"System database"* in your connection string.

If you don't know where to find the System database, open Access and check the output from this statement in the Immediate window.  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will open the Immediate window)

```vb
Debug.Print Application.DBEngine.SystemDb
```

My System database is  *C:\Users\hans\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System1.mdw*  Substitute yours in the code example below.

I'm not really proficient with Powershell, but this example ran without error for me.  (Be sure to change both `$Db` and `$SystemDb`.)

```bsh
$ScrUsr = $(whoami)
Write-Host $ScrUsr

$cmd = "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"
Write-Host $cmd

Function Invoke-ADOCommand($Db, $SystemDb)
{
  $connection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
  $ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$db;Jet OLEDB:System database=$SystemDb;"
  Write-Host $ConnectionString
  $connection.Open($ConnectionString)
  $discard = $connection.Execute($cmd)
  $connection.Close()
} 

$Db = "C:\Users\hans\AccessApps\Sample.accdb"
$SystemDb = "C:\Users\hans\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System1.mdw"

Invoke-ADOCommand -db $Db -SystemDb $SystemDb
```

Comment: nop, good one would be if one is using try and catch error handling to run it controlled, but for a starting Point & testing purpose it is usable. thanks again.