# How can I grant operation to an user in MS access by using C++ code?

Tags: ms-access

I've found a way to grant select to admin by VBA command
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937703/record-cannot-be-read-no-read-permission-on-msysobjects)

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"
```

But everytime I have to execute that in the Access. I want to execute that in my c++ code. I use the ADO + ATL COM way to operate the Access DB.

```
::CoInitialize(NULL);
    _RecordsetPtr m_pRecordset("ADODB.Recordset");
    _ConnectionPtr m_pConnection("ADODB.Connection");
    _bstr_t bstrSQL("select top 10 * from AppointmentStatus");  
    try
    {
        m_pConnection.CreateInstance("ADODB.Connection");
...
```