# Getting names of Access database tables with Matlab

Tags: ms-access, matlab, adodb

I'm trying to get a listing of all tables in an Access database using Matlab.

I'm so far using an actxobject and can successfull run queries against the database, but all methods I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201282/how-to-get-table-names-from-access) have failed.

I consistently get the error message 'No read permission on MSysObjects'. The query runs fine within the Access-program, but the implementation of my program does not allow me to store the query there.

So, my question is: Is there any way to list all the tables of an Access database through Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
conn = actxserver('ADODB.Connection');
connString = 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Nwind.mdb';
conn.Open(connString);

rs = conn.OpenSchema('adSchemaTables').GetRows;
tableNames = rs(3, ismember(rs(4,:),'TABLE') );
```

and the result is:

```
>> tableNames'
ans = 
    'Categories'
    'Customers'
    'Employees'
    'Order Details'
    'Orders'
    'Products'
    'Shippers'
    'Suppliers'
```