# How to store data from MATLAB to Access DB?

Tags: database, ms-access, matlab, video, neural-network

I want to store my results from neural network in MATLAB to Access database, and also store video with it to the same database. For other time when everyone result the same pic from neural network the output for him is video that was stored before in DB...

Can you help me?

Comment: A lot of errors in the question. I tried to edit it but failed to understand the last sentence. Please check, it should be in English.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the commercial [Database Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/database/) you may access your DB via Java scripting in MATLAB. See the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html) for further details about how to use Java from MATLAB.

First requirement for this approach is a JDBC driver for your database.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [ADO OLE Database Connection](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13621-ado-ole-database-connection) from File Exchange. Very fast and easy to use with Access database.

Install it and look at adodb_demo.m for code example.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100998/getting-names-of-access-database-tables-with-matlab) you can find an example of using ADODB object directly. It's the same approach used in the above submission.