# How to read all record from access database(.accdb) using C# automation

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to read all record from MS access database using automation(using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access) in C#.

I able to read record using ADO.net in C# but not using Automation.

Please help..
Thanks

Comment: You will need to do quite a lot of reading and then come back here with some code and notes on where you are stuck. Under the following search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=interop+%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bms-access%5D you will find quite a lot on Access and C#, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909644/how-can-i-extract-an-mdb-files-table-contents-to-text-in-c, this will give you key words to find articles both here and through googling.

Comment: Thanks,Remou provided links works for me.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a specific need to involve the Access user interface in this task, I recommend you don't do this. Instead, use [`OdbcConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.aspx) or [`OleDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to directly access and manipulate the database.