# Populate Combobox with Names of Only Selected MS Access Tables

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox, oledb

I need to populate the combobox with the names of some tables from an MS Access database. My problem is I don't know how I will repopulate the items when the program is opened again. One method I can think of is make a table that will hold all the table names to be listed in the combobox but I don't want to use that method because I don't want unnecessary tables in database.

Comment: Did you try this: [how-to-get-table-names-from-access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201282/how-to-get-table-names-from-access)

Comment: 1- read the comment above from Steve. 2 - there is no such thing as "unnecessary tables" if they are used for something. 3- the gain of this method is that you only list those tables that you want in combo box rather than all of them