# Get the name of the columns from a Access table by a Visual Basic

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to get the names of the table into a list so I can create an SQL table with them.

I was trying to do this with `information_scheme` just like SQL does, but MS Access doesn't support it.

Comment: You can use ADOX with MSAccess to query information about tables etc.  or see this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201282/how-can-i-get-table-names-from-an-ms-access-database

Comment: Thank you! Pretty useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether you are looking to obtain the column names per your question title:

> Get the name of the **columns** from a Access table by a Visual Basic

Or the table names per your question content:

> I'm trying to get the **names of the table** into a list so I can create an SQL table with them.

If the former, you can iterate over the [Fields collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/fields-collection-dao) of the relevant [TableDef object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/tabledef-object-dao) and query the `Name` property for each Field object.

For example, the following function will return an array of the field names held by the table with the supplied name:

```
Function FieldNames(strTbl As String) As String()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim def As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim idx As Integer: idx = 0

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set def = dbs.TableDefs(strTbl)

    Dim rtn() As String
    ReDim rtn(0 To def.Fields.Count - 1)

    For Each fld In def.Fields
        rtn(idx) = fld.Name
        idx = idx + 1
    Next fld
    FieldNames = rtn
End Function
```

Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) example output:

```
x = FieldNames("YourTable")
?x(0)
Field1
?x(1)
Field2
?x(2)
Field3
```

---

If instead you are looking to obtain an array of all **table names** within the database, you could iterate over the [TableDefs collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/tabledefs-collection-dao) within the database, as demonstrated by the following function:

```
Function TableNames() As String()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim def As DAO.TableDef
    Dim idx As Integer: idx = 0

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    Dim rtn() As String
    ReDim rtn(0 To dbs.TableDefs.Count - 1)

    For Each def In dbs.TableDefs
        rtn(idx) = def.Name
        idx = idx + 1
    Next def
    TableNames = rtn
End Function
```