# SQL Select statement from mutiple tables to fill datagridview

Tags: sql, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I have multiple tables, the tables themselves are named after the date they were created on; so for example 4/01/2021, 5/01/2021.. etc

The tables contain all the same columns.

But I'd like to create a SQL statement that allows me to return all the tables that were created between two dates and fill a Datagridview with all the records in those tables.

Ideally I want a "Created Last Week", "Created This week", "Created This Month" options. I can work out th syntax for the start and end dates. But I'm not sure what the correct way is to return the tables that fall between the dates.

I have looked at a few examples but none seem to work for me or be exactly what I'm after. Not sure if I can use `sys.tables` or if I need to use inner joins/left join etc to get this to work.

My tables are in a `Acccess.MDB` file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201282/how-can-i-get-table-names-from-an-ms-access-database  then  loop to splice together  THE table names into the joins part of a SELECT *  sql statement.  which joins depends on how you choose to handle missing data.  For example: SELECT * FROM  4/01/2021 INNER JOIN 5/01/2021 ON ...

Comment: Really should be 1 table with another field for identifying each set of records, which can be the date created. That would be a normalized structure. Then a CROSSTAB query is one way to pivot data. Otherwise, joining tables requires a master dataset with all possible values of whatever is the common identifier need to link with.

Comment: Unfortunately, saved query objects cannot be dynamic for inclusion of tables/fields. In VBA, could use QueryDefs to modify a saved query or build an SQL statement to set RecordSource of report. No idea how would be done in VB.net, C# or whatever your frontend is coded with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a *union query*:

[Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

However, as the tables included will vary, you must create the SQL of the query dynamically and then call the query to fill your datagridview.

**Note**: This is a terrible setup. You should, at the soonest and as suggested by @June7, change your schema to have *one table only* with a field holding your dates (your current table names).

Comment: cheers, i have just set out with what im trying to make. so im not too far into it. so i could change the structure of the tables and database. 

thank you for your ideas.

Comment: i seem to have run into a new problem. i cant get a SQL query to work that includes a date. my date is in dd/mm/yyyy format.  im trying to do `select * from Returnstoaction where
purchase_date = ("10/01/2021")`

Comment: Date expressions use _octothorpes_ and use the ISO sequenc for year-month-day: `select * from Returnstoaction where purchase_date = #2021/01/10#`.

Comment: thanks, this helped me i finally worked got it to work the correct way.